# In Advanced SubStation Alpha (Ass file) how can I animate each word as it is spoken?

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitle, video-subtitles

Hello I am trying to get Ass (Advanced SubStation Alpha) code to animate (highlight in green) each word as it is spoken and then have it revert back to white afterwards.  What happens with my code is very odd.  At first I cannot even see any text.  It then appears with multiple lines overlapped, partially hanging off the screen.  From this point it "kind of" works.  I can see the desired highlighting happening but because the text is all jumbled and overlapping it can hardly be called a success.

In case it is relevant I am using ffmeg to burn in the subtitles.  I am using the following command:

`ffmpeg -i FortuneTeller1.mp4 -vf "ass=FortuneTeller1.ass" Subtitled.mp4`

The resolution of the source video is 1080x1920 (vertical).

My ultimate goal is to burn Hormozi style text with per word animations.  I'm far from that so any input would be appreciated! If you need any additional info/code to help troubleshoot this please let me know what you need and I will provide it.

I have the following Ass code in the Events section:

```
Dialogue: 0,0:00:02.48,0:00:03.28,Default,,0,0,0,,{\c&H00FF00&\pos(640,480)}In{\c&H00FFFFFF&} the tapestry of time, a visitor from shadows past shall emerge, igniting flames of forgotten yearnings.
Dialogue: 0,0:00:03.48,0:00:04.28,Default,,0,0,0,,In {\c&H00FF00&\pos(640,480)}the{\c&H00FFFFFF&} tapestry of time, a visitor from shadows past shall emerge, igniting flames of forgotten yearnings.
Dialogue: 0,0:00:04.68,0:00:09.68,Default,,0,0,0,,In the {\c&H00FF00&\pos(640,480)}tapestry{\c&H00FFFFFF&} of time, a visitor from shadows past shall emerge, igniting flames of forgotten yearnings.
Dialogue: 0,0:00:09.88,0:00:01.48,Default,,0,0,0,,In the tapestry{\c&H00FF00&\pos(640,480)}of{\c&H00FFFFFF&} time, a visitor from shadows past shall emerge, igniting flames of forgotten yearnings.
Dialogue: 0,0:00:02.08,0:00:04.89,Default,,0,0,0,,In the tapestry of {\c&H00FF00&\pos(640,480)}time{\c&H00FFFFFF&}, a visitor from shadows past shall emerge, igniting flames of forgotten yearnings.
Dialogue: 0,0:00:06.89,0:00:10.49,Default,,0,0,0,,In the tapestry of time,{\c&H00FF00&\pos(640,480)}a{\c&H00FFFFFF&} visitor from shadows past shall emerge, igniting flames of forgotten yearnings.
Dialogue: 0,0:00:10.89,0:00:03.29,Default,,0,0,0,,In the tapestry of time, a {\c&H00FF00&\pos(640,480)}visitor{\c&H00FFFFFF&} from shadows past shall emerge, igniting flames of forgotten yearnings.
Dialogue: 0,0:00:03.69,0:00:07.49,Default,,0,0,0,,In the tapestry of time, a visitor {\c&H00FF00&\pos(640,480)}from{\c&H00FFFFFF&} shadows past shall emerge, igniting flames of forgotten yearnings.
Dialogue: 0,0:00:08.09,0:00:11.49,Default,,0,0,0,,In the tapestry of time, a visitor from {\c&H00FF00&\pos(640,480)}shadows{\c&H00FFFFFF&} past shall emerge, igniting flames of forgotten yearnings.
Dialogue: 0,0:00:11.89,0:00:04.89,Default,,0,0,0,,In the tapestry of time, a visitor from shadows {\c&H00FF00&\pos(640,480)}past{\c&H00FFFFFF&} shall emerge, igniting flames of forgotten yearnings.
Dialogue: 0,0:00:05.29,0:00:03.61,Default,,0,0,0,,In the tapestry of time, a visitor from shadows past {\c&H00FF00&\pos(640,480)}shall{\c&H00FFFFFF&} emerge, igniting flames of forgotten yearnings.
Dialogue: 0,0:00:03.65,0:00:04.09,Default,,0,0,0,,In the tapestry of time, a visitor from shadows past shall {\c&H00FF00&\pos(640,480)}emerge{\c&H00FFFFFF&}, igniting flames of forgotten yearnings.
Dialogue: 0,0:00:04.13,0:00:04.57,Default,,0,0,0,,In the tapestry of time, a visitor from shadows past shall emerge, {\c&H00FF00&\pos(640,480)}igniting{\c&H00FFFFFF&} flames of forgotten yearnings.
Dialogue: 0,0:00:04.61,0:00:04.97,Default,,0,0,0,,In the tapestry of time, a visitor from shadows past shall emerge, igniting {\c&H00FF00&\pos(640,480)}flames{\c&H00FFFFFF&} of forgotten yearnings.
Dialogue: 0,0:00:05.03,0:00:05.09,Default,,0,0,0,,In the tapestry of time, a visitor from shadows past shall emerge, igniting flames {\c&H00FF00&\pos(640,480)}of{\c&H00FFFFFF&} forgotten yearnings.
Dialogue: 0,0:00:05.13,0:00:05.55,Default,,0,0,0,,In the tapestry of time, a visitor from shadows past shall emerge, igniting flames of {\c&H00FF00&\pos(640,480)}forgotten{\c&H00FFFFFF&} yearnings.
Dialogue: 0,0:00:05.59,0:00:06.31,Default,,0,0,0,,In the tapestry of time, a visitor from shadows past shall emerge, igniting flames of forgotten {\c&H00FF00&\pos(640,480)}yearnings.{\c&H00FFFFFF&}.
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with the following (code pasted below).  Only issue that remains is the subtitle text after burned to video flickers the entire time.  The quest continues! :)

```
[Script Info]
ScriptType: v4.00+
PlayResX: 1080
PlayResY: 1920

[Aegisub Project Garbage]
Last Style Storage: Default
Video Position: 276

[V4+ Styles]
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, SecondaryColour, OutlineColour, BackColour, Bold, Italic, Underline, StrikeOut, ScaleX, ScaleY, Spacing, Angle, BorderStyle, Outline, Shadow, Alignment, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Encoding
Style: Default,Arial,32,&H00FFFFFF,&H000000FF,&H00000000,&H00000000,0,0,0,0,100,100,0,0,1,2,1,2,10,10,10,0
Style: Hormozi,The Bold Font,80,&H00FFFFFF,&H000A14E1,&H00000000,&H00000000,-1,0,0,0,100,100,0,0,1,2,3,8,10,10,10,1

[Events]
Format: Layer, Start, End, Style, Name, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Effect, Text
Dialogue: 0,0:00:00.24,0:00:00.32,Hormozi,,0,0,0,,{\c&H00FF00&}In{\c&H00FFFFFF&} the tapestry of time, a visitor from shadows past shall emerge, igniting flames of forgotten yearnings
Dialogue: 0,0:00:00.34,0:00:00.42,Hormozi,,0,0,0,,In {\c&H00FF00&}the{\c&H00FFFFFF&} tapestry of time a visitor from shadows past shall emerge igniting flames of forgotten yearnings
Dialogue: 0,0:00:00.46,0:00:00.96,Hormozi,,0,0,0,,In the {\c&H00FF00&}tapestry{\c&H00FFFFFF&} of time a visitor from shadows past shall emerge igniting flames of forgotten yearnings
Dialogue: 0,0:00:00.98,0:00:01.04,Hormozi,,0,0,0,,In the tapestry {\c&H00FF00&}of{\c&H00FFFFFF&} time a visitor from shadows past shall emerge igniting flames of forgotten yearnings
Dialogue: 0,0:00:01.10,0:00:01.38,Hormozi,,0,0,0,,In the tapestry of {\c&H00FF00&}time{\c&H00FFFFFF&} a visitor from shadows past shall emerge igniting flames of forgotten yearnings
Dialogue: 0,0:00:01.58,0:00:01.94,Hormozi,,0,0,0,,In the tapestry of time {\c&H00FF00&}a{\c&H00FFFFFF&} visitor from shadows past shall emerge igniting flames of forgotten yearnings
Dialogue: 0,0:00:01.98,0:00:02.12,Hormozi,,0,0,0,,In the tapestry of time a {\c&H00FF00&}visitor{\c&H00FFFFFF&} from shadows past shall emerge igniting flames of forgotten yearnings
Dialogue: 0,0:00:02.16,0:00:02.54,Hormozi,,0,0,0,,In the tapestry of time a visitor {\c&H00FF00&}from{\c&H00FFFFFF&} shadows past shall emerge igniting flames of forgotten yearnings
Dialogue: 0,0:00:02.60,0:00:02.94,Hormozi,,0,0,0,,In the tapestry of time a visitor from {\c&H00FF00&}shadows{\c&H00FFFFFF&} past shall emerge igniting flames of forgotten yearnings
Dialogue: 0,0:00:02.98,0:00:03.18,Hormozi,,0,0,0,,In the tapestry of time a visitor from shadows {\c&H00FF00&}past{\c&H00FFFFFF&} shall emerge igniting flames of forgotten yearnings
Dialogue: 0,0:00:03.22,0:00:03.61,Hormozi,,0,0,0,,In the tapestry of time a visitor from shadows past {\c&H00FF00&}shall{\c&H00FFFFFF&} emerge igniting flames of forgotten yearnings
Dialogue: 0,0:00:03.65,0:00:04.09,Hormozi,,0,0,0,,In the tapestry of time a visitor from shadows past shall {\c&H00FF00&}emerge{\c&H00FFFFFF&} igniting flames of forgotten yearnings
Dialogue: 0,0:00:04.13,0:00:04.57,Hormozi,,0,0,0,,In the tapestry of time a visitor from shadows past shall emerge {\c&H00FF00&}igniting{\c&H00FFFFFF&} flames of forgotten yearnings
Dialogue: 0,0:00:04.61,0:00:04.97,Hormozi,,0,0,0,,In the tapestry of time a visitor from shadows past shall emerge igniting {\c&H00FF00&}flames{\c&H00FFFFFF&} of forgotten yearnings
Dialogue: 0,0:00:05.03,0:00:05.09,Hormozi,,0,0,0,,In the tapestry of time a visitor from shadows past shall emerge igniting flames {\c&H00FF00&}of{\c&H00FFFFFF&} forgotten yearnings
Dialogue: 0,0:00:05.13,0:00:05.55,Hormozi,,0,0,0,,In the tapestry of time a visitor from shadows past shall emerge igniting flames of {\c&H00FF00&}forgotten{\c&H00FFFFFF&} yearnings
Dialogue: 0,0:00:05.59,0:00:06.03,Hormozi,,0,0,0,,In the tapestry of time a visitor from shadows past shall emerge igniting flames of forgotten {\c&H00FF00&}yearnings{\c&H00FFFFFF&}
```